# Is there an error in my angular project with submit button and PUT http://localhost:4200/napi/setting/numbers/, [object Object] error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I wanna submit form I catch this error:
*PUT http://localhost:4200/napi/setting/numbers/, [object Object]*

this is number.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControlOptions, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { BehaviorSubject, take } from 'rxjs';
import { PhoneNumbers } from '../../../models/phone-number.interface';
import { SettingService } from '../../../services/setting.service';
import { GlobalConstants } from '../../../shared/global-constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'farmonitor-emergency-number',
  templateUrl: './emergency-number.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emergency-number.component.scss'],
})
export class EmergencyNumberComponent implements OnInit {

    emergencyNumberGroup!: FormGroup;
    readonly numberFieldName = "number";
    phoneNumbers: PhoneNumbers[];
    data: any;
    error$: BehaviorSubject<string>;


    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private setService: SettingService,
        private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    ) {
        this.phoneNumbers = [];
        this.link = ["/user-setting"];
        this.error$ = new BehaviorSubject("");
    }

onSubmit(): void {
        // Send request to api server
        this.error$.next("");
        const num: PhoneNumbers = { id: this.numbers.value ,number: '' };
        this.setService.updateNumbers(num)
            .pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe({
                next: () => {
                    this.openSnackBar('Number saved', 'close');
            },
                error: (err: unknown) => {
                console.log(err);
                this.openSnackBar('Number did not saved', 'close');
            }
            });
    }

    private openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
        this.snackBar.open(message, action, { duration: GlobalConstants.SNACKBAR_DURATION });
    }
```

here is my number.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="emergencyNumberGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div><button class="action" type="submit" mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!emergencyNumberGroup.valid">submit</button></div>
</form>
```

and setting.service.ts:

```
updateNumbers(number: PhoneNumbers): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.put<string>(`/napi/setting/numbers/, ${number.id}`, number);
    }
```

It should be send data form to server and show the response.

Comment: can you check this.numbers.value if it is valid?

Comment: @SonuSindhu No, when I log this.numbers.value I catch error

Comment: where you defined the numbers variable?

Comment: In PhoneNumbers.Interface.ts

Comment: @SonuSindhu but I got empty array of log  this.numbers.value

Comment: check how you can get that number

Comment: Ok I get the array of numbers but the error is steal there

Comment: is it the same error? you can if it is array then you can - ${this.numbers.id.join(',')}

Answer (score 0):

In your service, the url seems KO. `/napi/setting/numbers/, ${number.id}` is not a valid url, it would make the string `/napi/setting/numbers/, 5`, whereas what ou want is `/napi/setting/numbers/5`.

So change your service code into this:

```
updateNumbers(number: PhoneNumbers): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.put<string>(`/napi/setting/numbers/${number.id}`, number);
}
```

Then, make sure `number.id` is actually a number by logging it.